# GNU make: Don't delete intermediate files on error that happened elsewhere

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say that I have a makefile:

```
.RECIPEPREFIX = +
.ONESHELL:

all: one

vars := one.a two.a three.a
.INTERMEDIATE: $(vars)

one: $(vars)
+ touch $@

%.a: %.b
+ touch $@

%.b:
+ if [ "$@" = "three.b" ];
+ then
+   exit 1;
+ fi
+ touch $@
```

and all the targets take a long time to finish.
If everything goes well, none of the intermediates (defined explicitly or implicitly) will be preserved. And that's good.

But, say that one target signals an error. Makefile stops and removes all intermediate targets even though there was no error signalled for them.

Variations of this problem are even more annoying when make is run in parallel.

How to prevent removing intermediate targets that were created successfully?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is what `.SECONDARY` is for.

You can read more info here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html and also here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html

John points out I didn't notice your desire to keep the intermediate files being removed on if the build doesn't fail.  I don't think there's any way to prevent make from deleting an intermediate file on failure, while still having it be deleted on success.

The only thing I can think of is to declare them `.SECONDARY`, then delete them yourself as part of your final recipe (for example, a recipe for the `all` target).  That recipe is only run if all other recipes succeeded, and if you declare them `.SECONDARY` they won't be rebuilt if not needed.  I'm not sure this will work as I haven't tried it.

Comment: I take the OP to be saying that they want their intermediate files preserved only in the event of a build failure, and even then, maybe only certain ones.  I think `.SECONDARY` would prevent any of them *ever* being deleted (automatically by `make`).  Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger thats exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: @MadScientist Since you are an expert on `make`, do you have best practices how to do said cleanup? Should I include it in the recipe after target has been created and dependency is no longer needed? `target: dependency; touch @; rm $<`

The files I am creating are also quite big (hundreds of GB) and I am trying to find a good way to save space.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suggesting in my response.